# JQGrid Sorting is not working - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sorting, jqgrid

I am trying to sort the each columns in my JQGrid but its not working. Please refer my code below and help me

//View Code

```
     $("#JQGridID").jqGrid({
                            url: '/Control/ActionResult/',
                            datatype: 'json',
                            mtype: 'POST',
                            colNames: ['Number', 'Unit'],
                            colModel: [
              { name: 'NNumber', index: 'Number', align: 'left', sortable: true, sorttype: 'int' },
              { name: 'NUnit', index: 'Unit', align: 'Center', sortable: true }
              ],                            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                            cmTemplate: { title: false },
                            width: widthValue - 15,
                            height: 435,
                            rowNum: 20,
                            rowList: [20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
                            viewrecords: true,
                            gridComplete: loadCompleteFunction,
                            altRows: true,
                            sortorder: 'desc',
                            sortname: 'Number',
                            sortable: true,
                            onSortCol: function (index, idxcol, sortorder) {
                    if (this.p.lastsort >= 0 && this.p.lastsort !== idxcol
                            && this.p.colModel[this.p.lastsort].sortable !== false) {
                        $(this.grid.headers[this.p.lastsort].el).find(">div.ui-jqgrid-sortable>span.s-ico").show();
                    }
                }
,
                            onSelectRow: showMessageDetails,
                            postData: {
                        },

                        loadError: function (xml) { alert('Unable to load result data.'); }
                    });
```

//Control code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetSearchPositionResult(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
        {
            _Object = new PositionModel();
            _Object.CurrentPage = page;
            _Object.PageRowCount = rows;
            _Object.load();
            var result = new
            {
                total = _Object.TotalPages,
                page = page,
                sort = sidx,
                sord = sord,
                records = _Object.TotalRows,
                            rows = _ObjectPM.SearchResult.Select(p => new
            {
                cell = new string[]{
                 p.Number,
                 p.Unit
                },sidx
            }).OrderBy(a => a.sidx).ToArray(),                };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Can you share you server side vcode - because this is where the sorting should take place

Comment: I have added control page code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `datatype: 'json'` the sorting of data (`sortable: true` in `colModel`) is not handled on client-side by jqGrid but it has to be handled on server-side by your code. In another words you need to sort your `_Object.SearchResult` by the column name which you will receive in `sidx` parameter (the sorting direction is passed in `sord` parameter).

Here you can find a sample project which can help with using jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC: [jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/61796)

Comment: Hi, Thaknx for ur reply. I have modified and uploaded the latest code. I have referred 'jqGrid in ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor' this exp but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: @Muthukumar What you have changed is adding sidx and sord to response. I have no idea what that suppose to change. You are suppose to use sidx and sord in your server side code and return dataset which is already sorted (it is your job to do the sorting). This is done in sample project in following line: `_productsRepository.GetProducts(filterExpression.ToString(), sortingName, request.SortingOrder.ToString(), request.PageIndex, request.RecordsCount, request.PagesCount.HasValue ? request.PagesCount.Value : 1))` <-- the sord and sidx are being passed to repository so it can sort the data.

Comment: this is something like - in the sample code they were passing sortingName as parameter. I have modified the code lik this <code>`rows = _ObjectPM.SearchResult.Select(p => new { cell = new string[]{ p.Number, p.Unit },sidx }).OrderBy(a => a.sidx).ToArray(),`

Comment: @Muthukumar `sidx` is holding the name from your columns and you have to sort your dataset by value of that column. Lets assume that the sidx contains value *Number*, then your code should look like this: `rows = _ObjectPM.SearchResult.OrderBy(p => p.Number).Select(p => new { id = p.Number, cell = new string[] { p.Number, p.Unit } }).ToArray()`. Of course you need to make that dynamic based on what comes in `sidx` and `sord`.

Comment: Thanks again. I have one more doubt. In this code `rows = _ObjectPM.SearchResult.OrderBy(p => p.Number).Select(p => new { id = p.Number, cell = new string[] { p.Number, p.Unit } }).ToArray(). ` How do you pass the dynamic value `sidx` instead of `p.Number`

Comment: @Muthukumar In general this is not easy question an strongly depends on entire architecture of your application. For simple scenario you can just if/case statements. You can try using Dynamic Linq Library. Maybe in your case it is better to do the sorting somewhere inside _ObjectPM so its closer to the database (databases usually are doing stuff faster then our code). It is your project you must choose solution which suits it the best.